# sub menu in Sherlock is jumping from its original position to wrong position

Tags: android, position, actionbarsherlock, tablet, submenu

The sub menu in action-bar of Sherlock (using an android tablet) jumps to the left during it is open.
I found that when I change and update the action-bar during the sub menu is open this happen, but I can't put the finger on the root of the problem.
How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the exact same question, having a sub menu that is open from a menu item with `showAsAction="always"`, when you call `supportInvalidateOptionMenu`, the items in the action bar are recycled, but the open menu is not closed. since its anchor view is recycled, it jumps to the top left corner.

My solution was to call `menu.close()` before invalidating the menu, in order to make sure it is close.

It is probably a bug of Sherlock, since I'm not using the latest version due to compatibility issues (removed apis in the new version) I can't tell if it is fixed or not.